SSIS Package runs on one server but getting an assembly component error on another server
I have an SSIS package that has been tested, and ran in Visual Studio 2019.  It was originally created, tested, and ran in VS 2017 but when I started having the issue I figured I would make sure it was working fine in 2019.  It was running fine on a server(Windows Server 2019) for a while now and we are working to migrate it to a newer server(Windows Server 2022).  On the new server I am getting the following error:

Error: 2024-08-27 11:50:10.94
Code: 0xC00490F7
Source: ConvertData ConvertData (GetExpirationDate [51])
Description: The managed pipeline component "DTSTransform.DerivedColumn.7" could not be loaded.  The exception was: Could not load type 'DTSTransform.DerivedColumn.7' from assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'..
End Error
Error: 2024-08-27 11:50:10.94
Code: 0xC0000036
Source: ConvertData ConvertData (SSIS.Pipeline)
Description: Failed to create COM Component Categories Manager due to error 0x80131600 "".
End Error
Error: 2024-08-27 11:50:10.94
Code: 0xC0048021
Source: ConvertData ConvertData (GetExpirationDate [51])
Description: The component is missing, not registered, not upgradeable, or missing required interfaces. The contact information for this component is "Derived Column;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;0".
End Error
Error: 2024-08-27 11:50:10.94
Code: 0xC004801F
Source: ConvertData ConvertData (SSIS.Pipeline)
Description: The component metadata for "GetExpirationDate" could not be upgraded to the newer version of the component. The PerformUpgrade method failed.
End Error

I thought maybe it was using some other version on the other server so I went and looked in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost
folder on the server it was working and the only dll in there is for version 15.  The new server does have version 15 and version 16 in there.  I am not sure if that makes any difference or not though.  I will also point out that the development box I built and ran this on had versions 11-14 but not 15 or 16.  Once again, not sure if that makes any difference but just wanted to mention it.
Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?
